# Java - Arrays and Method Parameters

Tags: java, arrays

How can I pass an array of filenames into the following method:

`public static double getFitness(int x, int y, int r, BufferedImage image);`

I currently have a method which creates an array of filenames from a given directory:

```
//Default image directory (to convert to greyscale).
static File dir = new File("images");
//Array of original image filenames.
static File imgList[] = dir.listFiles();

public static void processGreyscale(){
    if(dir.isDirectory()){
        for(File img : imgList){
            if(img.isFile()){
                //functions are carried out here.
            }
            else{
                                    //functions are carried out here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `getFitness` method scores the fitness of an image (`...BufferedImage image);`) based on the main region of interest (ROI).

What I am looking for is a way to run the `getFitness` method on the array of filenames; something like this:

`public static double getFitness(int x, int y, int r, fileArray)`

Can this be done?

### **UPDATE:**

Thank you all for your great suggestions; however, I should mention that I wish to leave the method parameters the same/unchanged as the fitness function is affected (negatively) if I change the passed parameters.

Is there any way that I can run the fitness function on all files/filenames within `imgList[]`?

What I'm hoping for is this:

```
public static double getFitness(int x, int y, int r, BufferedImage image){
    use filenames stored in imgList[] to take place of 'image'
    getFitness of `image`
    next image name
}
```

Is **this** possible?

Comment: You can create a new method with the same name, as long as the parameters are different.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html Overloading Methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

This is the method signature:

```
public static double getFitness(int x, int y, int r, File[] fileArray)
```

And this is the calling code:

```
getFitness(1, 1, 1, imgList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the array?

```
public static double getFitness(int x, int y, int r, File[] files);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify parameter type as File[] fileArray

Answer (score 0):

You can do 
`File fileArray[] = new File[numberOfFiles];` 
then specify a counter to store in the array such as `counter = 0` and increment the value of `counter` each time fileName is added to the array `fileArray[counter] = img.getName(); counter++;`

then send the array in your desired method `public static double getFitness(x, y, r, fileArray);`